# Voltage Fluctuation in house

Tags: electrical

Near my house there is a small industry which uses welding machine because of that i'm getting voltage fluctuation.When there is no work there is no issue.My doubt is that they have used 3 phase line  and mine is single phase.If their connection is a 3 phase one will such issue arises or its bcoz of the problem of the main transformer.Can anybody tell me how to overcome this.If any device is available in the market to overcome please suggest it would be a great help

Comment: What is the voltage when the business is not drawing power and when it?

Comment: Really isn't relevant if the small industry is 1Ø or 3Ø, what's relevant is if his equipment is fed by the same line.

Comment: Which country are you in?  North America, industry gets 3 phase of 277V (=480V) and houses get 120/240V - so different transformers obviously.  On 5 continents, industry gets 3 phases of 230V (=400V) and houses get 1 phase of 230V - *same transformer*.  So, it matters.

Comment: Mixed use neighborhoods are often older, where wild leg 120/240Δ could also be in play.

Answer (score 3):

All you can do is complain to your power provider about the power quality issue caused by the other customer.

Your single phase is going to be one of the 3 phases - there's no separation between them in typical distribution, you just don't get two of them delivered to your house.

You can use a UPS for sensitive loads, but it's not generally practical/affordable to have one that will supply the whole house.

Comment: Power companies are often unresponsive. You may need to get a local contractor to deploy a data logger at your service to prove unacceptable voltage.